# c++ convert string and int to char* not using the C standard library 

Tags: c++, string, integer, char

> not using the C standard library
>   do this in C++ ?

1. Convert string to char*
2. Covert  int to char*

If i had to convert string to int in c++ use something like this

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num;
    string str="2020";
    (stringstream)"2020">>num;
    cout<<num+2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can clarify a bit. What are you calling a "string" here -- a basic_string<char>, or something else? You say the above is an example of converting a "string" to an int, but in fact you're converting an array of char. And the answer to number one is seemingly so trivial that you must mean something more complicated than I'm seeing.

Comment: i have a function to which i must pass string and integer data but it accepts only char*. I am not sure if i get you but let me edit the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string str ("123");
    const char* c_str = str.c_str();

    char* so_bad = const_cast<char*>(c_str);

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << so_bad;

    int int_value;
    ss >> int_value;

    std::cout << int_value;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Convert `string` to `char *`" is impossible without the C++ standard library since `string` is a part of that library.

"Convert `int` to `char *`": I assume you mean putting the decimal representation of an `int` in some buffer. This is how it can be done for `unsigned`; doing the same for `signed int` means you have to take a possible `-` into account, and the corner case that arises from the fact that `-INT_MIN` is not well-defined.

```
unsigned n = SOME_VALUE;

char buffer[11]; // long enough for 32-bit UINT_MAX + NUL character
char *p = buffer + sizeof(buffer);

*--p = '\0';
do {
    *--p = '0' + n % 10;
    n /= 10;
} while (n);
```

`p` now points to the string representation of `n`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean you want a C++ solution using the C++ standard library (not using the C standard library).  If so try the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string stringString("2020");
    cout << "String String = " << stringString << endl;

    const char* charString = stringString.c_str();
    cout << "Char String = " << charString << endl;

    int charStringLen = stringString.size();
    for (int characterIndexCtr = 0; characterIndexCtr < charStringLen; ++characterIndexCtr)
    {
        cout << "Character At Index " << characterIndexCtr << " = " << charString[characterIndexCtr] << endl;
    }

    stringstream stringStream(stringString);
    int integerNumber;
    stringStream >> integerNumber;
    cout << "Integer = " << integerNumber << endl;
    cout << "Integer + 2 = " << integerNumber + 2 << endl;

    cout << "Press Enter To End Program ... ";
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you count Boost as stdlib, but [lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) can cast char*s to whatever you want:

```
char* foo = "123"
int bar = boost::lexical_cast(foo);
```

And the other way round:

```
int foo = 123;
std::string bar = boost::lexical_cast(foo);
your_function(bar.c_str());
```

It's using stringstream behind the scenes, but is a lot easier to use.
Also, you can't just convert an int to char*, as the memory the char* is pointing to has to be allocated somewhere.

Comment: They can and I used it for all of a few minutes until I saw how useless it was when you got an exception, not to also mention that there is no way to imbue a locale or set any other kind of formatting. I believe they have themselves seen the flaws in it and are replacing it with something much better.

Comment: definitely nice to know. the actual question was not intended to be complex and i changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Convert `string` to `char *`

```
std::vector<char> vec( str.begin(), str.end() );
vec.push_back( '\0' );
char * data = &vec[0];
```

Convert `string` to `int`

```
std::istringstream iss(str);
int i;
if( !iss >> i )
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "Invalid conversion from " << str << " to integer";
    throw std::invalid_argument( oss.str() );
}
```

Your second answer was close to the way to do it. Note there is a boost::lexical_cast which does pretty much the same, but has the huge downside of a meaningless bad_cast exception that gives no context information and therefore renders it almost useless in my opinion.